# Highlight Entire Row when cell is selected without lose the original formats of the orignal row?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

The problem is when I highlight a row with some color the original color of the row is gone, so I tried this code, and again, it's removing the original format and color for the row

This is the code from http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/highlightrow.html

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
        Const cnNUMCOLS As Long = 256
        Const cnHIGHLIGHTCOLOR As Long = 36  'default lt. yellow
        Static rOld As Range
        Static nColorIndices(1 To cnNUMCOLS) As Long
        Dim i As Long
        If Not rOld Is Nothing Then 'Restore color indices
            With rOld.Cells
                If .Row = ActiveCell.Row Then Exit Sub 'same row, don't restore
                For i = 1 To cnNUMCOLS
                    .Item(i).Interior.ColorIndex = nColorIndices(i)
                   Next i
            End With
        End If
        Set rOld = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Resize(1, cnNUMCOLS)
        With rOld
            For i = 1 To cnNUMCOLS
                nColorIndices(i) = .Item(i).Interior.ColorIndex
            Next i
            .Interior.ColorIndex = cnHIGHLIGHTCOLOR
        End With
    End Sub
```

So, what shall I do with this problem? How can I retain the range's historical color so that when I deselect the row it reverts properly?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this code- it works fine for me. I'm using 2003, though, no access to 2010 at the moment. Do you have any other code that might be interfering with this? It's not very long, have you stepped through it to make sure it's doing what you think it is?

Comment: thnks for your replay but the code works gr8 with excel 2003,but with excel 2010 its fail ,so what shall i do ???.

Comment: ok, tried this on 2007, works fine, BUT it leaves the highlight, whenever the macro is stopped (did that by using stop/setback in the VBE), but it works again fine afterwards - maybe this will point you in the right direction. Have you tried the code on a clean workbook?

Answer (score 1):

Fake it with conditional formatting.

Use conditional formatting to set the cells to the color(s) you want. As a condition, use the formula `=ROW()=$C$12`

Then (in this example) change `C12` to the row you want to be highlighted. set it to a row outside your range to remove the highlighting.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 3) = Target.Row
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a clever idea, +1. Can I suggest though that you supply a little code for the OP? At the risk of offending, I'm not sure he'll get it with just this description.

Comment: how to use conditional formtting with specific range,so why  specific range C12???

Comment: $C$12 was just a reference point - you can set it to any cell you want. By putting a row number in the reference cell, that row will be highlighted

Comment: The downside to this method is that the user loses the ability to undo any of their previous actions.  Essentially, every time the user changes the selection the Undo-stack is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that doesn't clear the Undo-stack every time the user changes the selection.  This preserves the normal undo behavior which is important and often essential.

### Define a Name

This is -not- a named range.  It will be a name that stores a value without having to store it inside of a cell.  We will use it to store the number of the active/selected row.  By storing it in a defined name instead of in a cell, we preserve Excel's Undo-stack.

1. Go to **Formula** > **Names Manager** > **New**.
2. Set the following field values:

   **Name:** ActiveRow

   **Scope:** Workbook

   **Refers to:** 1
3. Click **OK**.

### Add VBA Code to the Worksheet Module

Add the following code to the worksheet module where you want the active row to be highlighted.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Excel.ThisWorkbook.Names("HighlightRow").Value = Excel.Selection.Row
End Sub
```

### Add Conditional Formatting to the Worksheet

1. Select all all cells in the entire worksheet.
2. Go to **Home** > **Conditional Formatting** > **New Rule**
3. Under -Select a Rule Type-, click **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**.
4. Click **Format** and define your formatting.
5. Set the formula to:

   =ROW()=ActiveRow

   ("ActiveRow" is the defined name you set up earlier.)

That's it!